# Pagination without Javascript

Tags: html, css, pagination

I'm trying to create page numbers and found this interesting codePen: https://codepen.io/p-ziegler/pen/bmdaaN

```css
.b,
input[type="radio"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.b {
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0.01;
    margin-left: -16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.p {
    display: none;
}

#p1:checked ~ .p1,
#p2:checked ~ .p2,
#p3:checked ~ .p3 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="b">1</div><input type="radio" name="p" id="p1" checked>
    <div class="b">2</div><input type="radio" name="p" id="p2">
    <div class="b">3</div><input type="radio" name="p" id="p3">
    <div class="p p1">Page 1</div>
    <div class="p p2">Page 2</div>
    <div class="p p3">Page 3</div>
</div>
```

I like that Javascript isn't required here. But the problem is I want to switch the page numbers to be at the bottom below the content, and make the content above the number set instead. But when I switched them, all the contents disappeared. Can you please let me know how to get it to work?

Comment: You probably need to keep the html as it is, but you could make use of flexbox and the order property in css

Comment: Instead of using radio boxes, consider using `:target` instead: https://codepen.io/dominikwilkowski/pen/qBNrbzv. That way you don't depend on the order of your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments, a better way to manage routes is using the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo class in CSS over radio inputs.
That way you don't need to worry about source order of you HTML.
A common problem with that solution though is the default page.
See below a working example of a code snippet with a default page (Home).

In this code we hide all the sections. Then we make the default page visible (`#home` in this case) and then hide the default block again when the `:target` selector is satisfied.
The specificity of those selectors is important important to make sure the default section isn't hidden when it's being selected.

```css
/* hide all by default */
section {
    display: none;
}
/* show home by default */
#page1 {
    display: block;
}
/* on target show */
section:target {
    display: block;
}
/* on target hide all siblings that are the default, if default is select itself it won't have sibling called home */
section:target ~ #page1 {
    display: none;
}


/* The below is just for styling */
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
    background: gray;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS only SPA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#page1">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page2">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page3">3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <section id="page3">
            <h1>Page 3</h1>
            <p>
                Proin ante arcu, hendrerit ac diam sagittis, sollicitudin posuere ante. Etiam egestas eros at nunc venenatis eleifend eu at tellus.
            </p>
        </section>

        <section id="page2">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
            <p>
                Integer porttitor vitae est vel suscipit. Fusce placerat justo at libero aliquam maximus.
            </p>
        </section>
        
        <section id="page1">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
            <p>
                Ut aliquet sit amet urna non porta. Maecenas dignissim, sem eget pulvinar luctus, ex dolor posuere magna, ut elementum quam eros vel nulla.
            </p>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear clarification, Dominik. That helps a lot.

Comment: No worries. Feel free to upvote and mark this as the answer so I get my imaginary internet points :)

Comment: Done. You've got the points you deserve!